# How do I get Ministers?

Tags: tropico-4

In Tropico 4, how do I get a Minister so I cna use edicts, as in the Minister of Education or the Minister of Defense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to build a [ministry](http://tropico.wikia.com/wiki/Ministry) and then you can hire whoever you want. Of course, you need to have people that can do the job. For example, for a military minister you need a good general and so forth.
EDIT: You can also hire foreign ministers but that's not advisable as far as my experience goes.

Comment: It's a viable choice early on when you *really* need those edicts but there are either no local candidates or they're all incompetent idiots, which can *really* screw you over in the random events.

Comment: Well, i usually have to hire the military minister because my own people are dumb. Then i can start enslaving my people. Militariy dictatorship FTW!